# Ionic 4 showWhen hideWhen

Tags: html, ionic-framework, angular-directive, ionic4

I'm trying to use the same html for both web and device and have cases where I need to show/hide either web html or device html.

Where are the [showWhen](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/show-hide-when/ShowWhen/) and [hideWhen](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/show-hide-when/HideWhen/) directives in Ionic 4? If they are gone have they been replaced with something else?

As of now all I can find is [some test page](https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/content/api/hide-when-demo.html) but that doesn't say much.

Answer (score 8):

For upgrading my app to ionic 4 I used this alternative https://ionicframework.com/docs/utilities/platform to show the right buttons based on the device's OS, it works great and very easy to implement:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'update-password',
  templateUrl: './update-password.component.html'
})
export class UpdatePasswordComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    public platform: Platform
  ) { }
```

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Update Password</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-button (click)="dismiss()">
        <ion-text color="primary" *ngIf="platform.is('ios')">Cancel</ion-text>
        <ion-icon name="md-close" *ngIf="!platform.is('ios')"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Ionic 4 has these directives;

`ion-hide-when`

and

```
ion-show-when
```

for example if you want to show only in android;

`<ion-show-when platform="android"> 
        stuff 
 </ion-show-when>`

## UPDATE

Apparently, these directives have just removed from Ionic 4 in the last beta version. See this [link](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/16214#issuecomment-435932118)

Comment: Angular complains that `'ion-show-when' is not a known element`. Do you have a link to the docs or some other source?

Comment: Hi! you are right. Apparently, these directives have just removed from Ionic 4 in the last beta version. See this [link](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/16214#issuecomment-435932118)

Answer (score 0):

There is an Ionic 4 code pen [here](https://codepen.io/brandyscarney/pen/ZmjJgV?editors=1100) which shows how you can achieve the same effect as the removed directives with styles, e.g. this span will show on iOS only.

`<span class="hide show-ios">Show iOS</span>`